# Windows 10 doesn't boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning

Windows 10 stopped booting.

I changed the size of the system partition and created a new partition. And now, right after the BIOS screen, the message appears:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot device
> or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key

I discovered that when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> during the BIOS screen, there is an empty item in the list of partitions to boot:

[image: Boot options]

And when I select it, Windows boots as usual. The option with an SSD on which C:\Windows does not work.

bcdedit output:

```
C:\Windows\system32>bcdedit

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {9b987b00-d211-11ee-8aa1-bea153bcfc73}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {9b987b00-d211-11ee-8aa1-bea153bcfc73}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: How did you resize the Windows partition? Did you use Disk Management?

Comment: Yes, I used Windows' Disk Management to shrink the partition. And then diskpart via cmd, to create an additional Windows RE partition. I did this at least 3 times, deleting the newly created partition each time (I changed my mind about the partition sizes)

Comment: Normally this shouldn't have caused such a problem. Try to do [Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html). When/if you manage to get the computer booting again, you should check the disk SMART attributes. If you don't have an app for that, use [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/?PageSpeed=noscript).

Comment: Startup Repair is the first thing I tried and it could not fix the problem. SMART looks good (in a Samsung tool). chkdsk shows no error too

Comment: Have you changed the order of the partitions with `diskpart`? It's a dangerous tool since it doesn't check much. Did you touch the EFI partition?

Comment: I shrank the system partition freeing some space at the end of the SSD space. Then created a new Windows RE partition in that freed space. Also I removed original Windows RE partition at the beginning of the SSD space, so it's a unused range now

Comment: If I understood right, you have changed the order of the partitions, which can cause a problem to Windows, as it uses for some references the partition number on the disk. I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If Startup Repair can't do its work on the disk, some
serious damage was caused, probably by `diskpart`.

I'm afraid you will need to reinstall Windows after saving
your data.

You could try to install Windows from USB into the
current Windows partition, in the hope that it won't
erase all your apps and settings.

If this doesn't work, delete all the partitions
while installing and allocate the Windows
partition to start with to be the right size,
leaving the rest of the drive as unallocated.